# File_put_contents(C:\...):failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: laravel-5

Estoy teniendo el siguiente error al cambiar la aplicación de ordenador:

```
file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\libreir\storage\framework/sessions/rvegGXCQkd34O6PyYQI6GlQ2j0pTSkAZio5Z02Mw): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo resolverlo?
Ya he probado con `php artisan cache:clear` con `php artisan config:cache` y con `chmod -R 777 app/storage`, 
`composer dump-autoload`

Por cierto, el `chmod -R 777 app/storage` me dice que no encuentra archivo o directorio, le cambié el nombre a la aplicación a libreir pero por lo visto aunque he probado con `chmod -R 777 libreir/storage` sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: un chmod en una ruta windows?

Comment: Es una respuesta que he encontrado, me ha parecido extraño a mi también pero bueno por intentarlo...

Comment: igual tu ruta esta extraña trata de que sea la misma barra no ambas

Comment: Utiliza virtualización o contenedores para evitar estos inconvenientes.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a usar homestead por ejemplo?

Comment: Homestead, Docker, Kubernetes, etc...